# Speeding up a postgres query (which works on 2 tables)

Tags: performance, postgresql, join

I am doing, in postgresql, something like this:

```
select A.first, 
       count(B.second) as count, 
       array_agg(A.second) as second,
       array_agg(A.third) as third, 
       array_agg(B.kids) as kids 
from A join B on A.first=B.second 
group by A.first;
```

And it's taking forever (also because the tables are pretty big). Limiting the output to 10 row and looking with explain analyze told me there's a nested loop which is huge and takes most of the time.

Is there any way in which I can write this query (which I'll then use in CREATE TABLE AS to create a new table) to speed it up, while conserving the same output, which is what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the execution plan (using explain analyze) and the definition of all the indexes defined on both tables. More information regarding performance questions are here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: There were no indexes in the original table. Creating some of them, the ones I needed, was enough to speed up the query by several orders of magnitude. I guess the key concept I learnt today is: "having your indexes working". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the column bring used as a foreign key is indexed:

```
create index b_second on b(second);
```

Without such an index, every row of `a` would cause a table scan of `b`, which would make your query crawl.

Comment: Much better, thank you! (I don't know why I thought I had to work on the query instead than on the table)